# How can I pass information from a Python code to a web information display?

Tags: python, user-interface, heroku, web-applications, beautifulsoup

I want to make a website with a function similar to https://www.howmanypeopleareinspacerightnow.com/, where I have a website information display that refreshes regularly displaying the water flow of a river through town. I am scraping the data using Beautiful Soup and would like to create a website that uses my python-processed data to generate pre-determined website content (e.g. 'The water is high right now, it has a flow rate of XXX/s' or 'The water is low right now').

From what I've read, I could create a Python app that is hosted on heroku, but then I would have to make a GUI in the program, right? How can I turn my program into an information source for an html page without having to have a user run a program?

I feel like there is a name for this and yet my Googling has not turned up anything so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a dynamic SPA (Single Page App).

You'll want and app server to host the backend, which will handle routing and serving up the dynamic content (water flow rate).

Then you'll want some front end code to render a nice UI and display the content the backend provides.

It sounds like you want to use python (as per the question tag).

A fast way to achieve this is to create a python Flask app. Flask will allow you to build an app server. In addition Flask has a 'template engine', Jinja2, which allows you to create UIs by combing HTML and python objects.

For example:

Create a folder called `waterproject` and `waterproject/templates/`
Then create 2 files, `waterproject/app.py` and `waterproject/templates/index.html`

```
# waterproject/app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def read_water_level():
    with open('/file/where/data/is/stored.txt') as file:
        water_level = file.read()

    return water_level

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():

    render_template('index.html', water_level=read_water_level())

@pp.route('/waterlevel', methods=['GET'])
def get_water_level():
    return json.dumpss({'waterlevel': read_water_level()})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost',debug=True)
```

Above we create 2 routes. One to serve the main page, and another an api endpoint that will only return the water level. This end point will be used to allow the frontend to automatically poll the backend for the water level, without having to re render (or refresh) the entire page.
Also it is assumed your web scraper is saving the water level in the file at '/file/where/data/is/stored.txt'

Then you would create the .html file (index.html) the above route renders.

```
# in /waterproject/templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>Water Level of River</title> 
    <style> 
        body { 
            text-align: center; 
        } 

        #water { 
            color: blue; 
        } 
    </style> 

    <script>
        var get_water_level = function() {
            $.get( "/waterlevel", function( data ) {
              $( "#water" ).html( data['waterlevel'] );
            });
        };
        var interval = 1000 * 60 * X; // where X is your every X minutes

        setInterval(get_water_level, interval);

    </script>
</head> 

<body>
    <div id="water">
        {{water_level}}
    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Notice how this html file has the `{{water_level}}` object embedded into the html. This is not proper html, but the template engine Flask employs allows us to effectively pass the `water_level` object from the app server's python code into the html document.

In addition, the .html page has some javascript in it to get the water level every X minutes, and update the page. So if a user visits your page and stays on it for 10 minutes, the page will automatically be refreshing every minute.

To deploy the app check out Flask's Documentation, there are some good options and instructions there, including instructions for Heroku.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/

*Note I haven't actually run this code but it should give you a good starting point.
Also its good practice to organize your css, javascript, and html in different files, but for such a small app, and to keep things simple everything is shown in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Flask, you can generate your content through python and display it easily with Flask.

Comment: thanks, flask has shown up in some searches and I think it could be what I need to run the code. But what about the front-end aesthetics? From what I understand, flask is limited in that way, thus my comment about the UI?

Comment: @ayduh, with a little html and css knowledge, you can style the page easily and flask allows you to implement JavaScript as well into your page.

Answer (score 0):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is the go-to way to create web pages with Python - it has a pretty comprehensive [tutorial](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/), and will handle all of the back-end stuff. You'll still need to figure out hosting; cloud-services (like AWS or Azure) play nicely with Django, or you can host from your own computer.

For front-end development, you can use a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) designer, which will let you drag and drop to create your page. You can then export your page and use it as a template in Django. If your site is more complex, you'll want to learn some basic text-based HTML skills.